# Render large list of images React Native

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render around 1200 items with images carousel in react native like shown on the screen below

[image]

`FlatList` works works so slow. Surprisingly, in case with images, `ScrollView` works better, but when it goes up 1200 elements, it works slow as hell.

Does somebody know how is that possible to render such amount of elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try these few props that help control the amount of items rendered like `windowSize`, `maxToRenderPerBatch` , and `initialNumToRender` .
It might helps with the performance

Comment: FlatList also has these props since FlatList is built using VirtualizedList, and as the docs states `VirtualizedList should only really be used if you need more flexibility than FlatList provides, e.g. for use with immutable data instead of plain arrays.`

Comment: @UgurEren my bad, thanks for reminding me

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try that